# Imager Sharpening Kernel producing odd result C#

Tags: c#, image-processing

I'm making a small app, where you can sharpen or blur an image in C#. So far blur is working flawlessly with any kernels of all sizes. However sharpening seems to cause this weird noisy/static image (something you'd see on a TV with no signal > see below). I've recoded this multiple times, and this time I tried to copy a solution from python, in case I keep messing it up somehow. Here's what I have for sharpening:

```cs
Color[,] clone = ud.CurrentSelected._bitmap; //gets the current image as a matrix
int[,] kernel = {{0, -1, 0}, {-1, 5, -1}, {0, -1, 0}};
int offset = 1;
int size = 100; //Image is 100x100 atm
for (int x = 0; x < size - offset; x++) {
  for (int y = 0; y < size - offset; y++) {
    NonDisplayedColour acc = Color.Black; //custom struct for storing and casting to regular Color without bounds -> not for displaying
    for (int A = 0; A < 3; A++) {
      for (int B = 0; B < 3; B++) {
        int deltaX = x + A - offset;
        int deltaY = y + B - offset;
        NonDisplayedColour pixel = ud.CurrentSelected._bitmap[deltaX, deltaY];
        int r = pixel.R * kernel[A, B];
        int g = pixel.G * kernel[A, B];
        int b = pixel.B * kernel[A, B];
        acc.R += r;
        acc.G += g;
        acc.B += b;
      }
    }
    clone[x,y] = acc;
  }
}
ud.CurrentSelected._bitmap = clone;
```

This is just the calculation part, what displays the image is this:

```cs
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(ud.CurrentSelected._bitmap.Width, ud.CurrentSelected._bitmap.Height);
for (int x = 0; x < b.Width; ++x) {
  for (int y = 0; y < b.Height; ++y) {
    b.SetPixel(x, y, ud.CurrentSelected._bitmap[x, y]);
  }
}
```

The `NonDisplayedColour` struct is just this, if anyone wants to know:

```cs
public struct NonDisplayedColour {
  public NonDisplayedColour(int r, int g, int b) {
    R = r;
    G = g;
    B = b;
    A = 255;
  }
  public int A;
  public int R;
  public int G;
  public int B;
        
  public static implicit operator Color(NonDisplayedColour c) {
    return Color.FromArgb((byte) c.A, (byte) c.R, (byte) c.G, (byte) c.B);
  }
  public static implicit operator NonDisplayedColour(Color c) {
    return new NonDisplayedColour(c.R, c.G, c.B) {A = c.A};
  }
}
```

The end result, is the [following image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyZtJ.png).

Thanks for the help in advance.
PS.: I know locking bits would be much faster, but I'm going for simplicity rather than speed and SetPixel (to me at least) is much simpler.

Comment: There are too many problem with this code. 1. You're using all integer values: the RGB values need to be calculated using `float` or `double` precision, then normalize if the value exceeds the boundaries 2. The filter offset is `int filterOffset = (filterWidth - 1) / 2`: with a Matrix of `3x3`, both offsets `= 1` 3. As a consequence, the external loops are in the range `[filterOffset : bitmap.Height - filterOffset]` 4. As a consequence, the internal loops are in the range `[-filterOffset : filterOffset]`.

Comment: Applying a multiplier Factor and Bias can help, since of course these are floating point values. Also, note that the convolution only treats Matrices, so the convolution of a Sharpen filter is the same as a Blur filter, except the Matrices values. I doubt that the Blur filter works when the Sharpen filter is like this. -- I suggest to use `Bitmap.LockBits` to apply the convolution to memory data: using `SetPixel()` is really not recommended with this kind of operations.

Comment: @Jimi
Changing all the values to `float` doesn't affect the output at all. I know the offset is 1, that's what I have set.
3 - I know that, I'm ignoring the outer boundaries - for now.
4 - Yes, I also know that.

Here's an image of what the blur filter does. I'm pretty sure it's correct. https://i.imgur.com/nTGUNYY.png

Comment: You have hard-coded an `offset` to `1` (you shouldn't, this implies 3x3 matrices only), but your outer loops begin from `0` instead of `offset` and the internal loop are in the range `[0;2]` instead of `[-offset;offset]`. You also need to consider the bitmap Stride (the actual width of a Scanline) and the bytes per Color (if you only use 32bpp Images, then it's always `4`). So, define first the pixel size: `int pixelSize = Image.GetPixelFormatSize([Bitmap].PixelFormat) / 8)`, then the buffer position in external loops  is `bufferOffset = offsetY * [Image].Stride + offsetX * pixelSize`. [...]

Comment: [...] The internal loops then use the buffer offset to define the filter offset, as `filterOffset = bufferOffset + (filterX * pixelSize) + (filterY * [Image].Stride)`. You have to revisit you `A` and `B` values as described (possibly, using more distinctive names, which express the function, so it's clear what these are meant for, when others read your code). I could post the sum of all this, if you want.